# Check which element mouse is over to control visiblity of another div

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to build a menu which detects hover states and hide/shows relevant divs depending on where the mouse is.  I need to do this with Prototype.js.

The menu looks something like this :

```
========ONE========TWO======THREE=======FOUR======FIVE======

============================================================
------------------- BIG MIDDLE DIV -------------------------
============================================================

============================================================
-------------------- TARGET HIDDEN DIV ---------------------
============================================================
```

When you mouse over link one,two,three.. it will show the related target div. The trick is when you mouseout, it needs to keep that div visible if you are on the middle div or the active state div.  If you mouseout anywhere else in the body it needs to hide.  Here is updated code based off the answer so far.

```
<ul><li #id="one">one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li></ul>
<div id="middleBar"></div>

<div id="container-one">1</div>

<div id="container-two">2</div>

<div id="container-three">3</div>

<div id="container-four">4</div>

<script>
   MouseOff = true;
function getTarget(event) {
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;
    return el.nodeType == 1? el : el.parentNode;
}

var ShowDiv = function(activeDiv){
    $(activeDiv).addClassName('isActive');
    var activeSibs = $(activeDiv).siblings();
    activeSibs.invoke('removeClassName', 'isActive');
};

var HideDiv = function(){
    if(MouseOff){
      $$('div').invoke('removeClassName','isActive');
    }
};

$$('li').invoke('observe','mouseenter',function(){
    console.log(getTarget(event));
    MouseOff = false;
    var linkName = this.innerHTML;
    var activeDiv = 'container-' + linkName;
    ShowDiv(activeDiv);    
});


$$('li').invoke('observe','mouseleave',function(){
    MouseOff = true;
    HideDiv();
});

 $$('#middleBar').invoke('observe','mouseenter',function(){
       console.log(getTarget(event));
        MouseOff = false;
    });
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle of this :

http://jsfiddle.net/TqMtK/5/

To further clarify what I am trying to achieve, once the div is activated it needs to stay visible while on that nav trigger, the middle bar, or the active div itself.  Something else I was thinking was to use that getTarget function to always check what element the mouse is above, but this just feels wrong to me and does not seem very efficient.  Any opinions on that?

UPDATE : Still trying to work through this.. now I am a little closer and the flag is set correctly when over middle div, but when it goes over the active div it resets the flag and the div disappears.  I tried adding back a timeout.. here is latest attempt :

http://jsfiddle.net/TqMtK/7/

UPDATE : Ok I think I might have this, at this point I would like to just hear any feedback on this solution.  I found that because the active class is being added dynamically the observer method must be  included in the function that creates it : ShowDiv.  Here is what I got :

http://jsfiddle.net/TqMtK/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: tues night. I am sure this can be more succinct. Perhaps it is just my browser but I notice that I can only mouse over Panel1 and show that it doesn't disappear, the other Panels (because of their positioning) leave a space which is the "body" and I close on that. Hopefully this is a bit better.

http://jsfiddle.net/TqMtK/12/

```
var tabPanels = {
    options : {
        activePanel : "",
        activeTab : ""
    },
    showPanel : function(panel){
        this.hidePanel();
        this.options.activePanel = 'container-' + panel;
        this.options.activeTab = panel;
        $(this.options.activePanel).addClassName('isActive').setAttribute('panel',panel);
    },
    hidePanel : function(panel){
        if(Object.isElement($(panel)) && $(panel).hasAttribute('panel') ){
            if($(panel).readAttribute('panel') == this.options.activeTab ){
                return;
            }else{
               if(!this.options.activePanel.blank()){
                  $(this.options.activePanel).removeClassName('isActive');
               } 
            }
        }else{
           if(!this.options.activePanel.blank()){
              $(this.options.activePanel).removeClassName('isActive');
           } 
        }
    }
}
document.observe('mouseover', function(e){
    switch(e.target.id){
        case 'middleBar':
        break;
        case 'one':
        case 'two': 
        case 'three': 
        case 'four':
            tabPanels.showPanel(e.target.id);
        break;
        default:
           tabPanels.hidePanel(e.target.id);  
    }       

})
```

Comment: Cool, thanks I will try this.  If user is off the middleBar it needs to hide, but first check that it is not over the initial trigger or the .isActive class.  I think I understand how I can do all this using that flag variable.

Comment: actually, since you have a timer of .500, you might just be able to set the value, then check within your setTimeOut callback rather than putting it in the hide func. - just thinking out loud.

Comment: Yes the timeout was creating other bugs and confusing the topic so I removed it.  I tried something along your solution of adding a flag but do not think this solves my problem.  I may not have described it very well but once the div is activated it needs to stay visible while on that nav trigger, the middle bar, or the active div itself.  The flag is set false as soon as it moves off the nav trigger (which is what is desired unless the mouse moves off and onto the middle).  Here is latest fiddling..  http://jsfiddle.net/TqMtK/4/

Comment: hey, see the original post from me. I updated a fiddle. I hope I am close to what you need. I know sometimes its hard to get what a user is looking for. I hope I am not too far offbase. Basically, if you mouse on a tab, it opens.. mousingoff to middle div, shows tab still open, until you mouseover another tab.

Comment: Thanks for trying +1, not what I need though.  I need it to disappear if it is anywhere else in the dom besides those 3 elements.  I think I figured it out finally with the last fiddle pasted in my post.  I dont really know what to do with this question at this point other than I fear my code is a bit smelly and hope for feedback on a "better way".

Comment: I updated, hopefully this is more succinct. See original post with new fiddle.

Comment: Hey I just noticed your updates, I posted my solution as well.  Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering I finally found a working solution for this.  Thanks to the idea from james I went the route of setting a flag depending on which element the mouse was over.  That combined with a timeout allowed me to keep running checks on the mouse location.  Part of my problem was where I was invoking the observe event on the class that was dynamically added from `ShowDiv()`, when I moved it in to that function I was able to get it to work.  Here is the js I ended up with

```
MouseLocator = 'off';
var ShowDiv = function(activeDiv){
    $(activeDiv).addClassName('isActive');
    var activeSibs = $(activeDiv).siblings();
    activeSibs.invoke('removeClassName', 'isActive');
    $$('.isActive').invoke('observe','mouseenter',function(){
    MouseLocator = 'on';
    });

    $$('.isActive').invoke('observe','mouseleave',function(){
      MouseLocator = 'off';
      setTimeout(function(){HideDiv()},500);
    });
};

var HideDiv = function(){
    if(MouseLocator == 'off'){
      $$('div').invoke('removeClassName','isActive');
    }
};

$$('li').invoke('observe','mouseenter',function(){
    MouseLocator = 'on';
    var linkName = this.innerHTML;
    var activeDiv = 'container-' + linkName;
    ShowDiv(activeDiv);    
});
$$('li').invoke('observe','mouseleave',function(){
    MouseLocator = 'off';
    setTimeout(function(){HideDiv()},500);
});
 $$('#middleBar').invoke('observe','mouseenter',function(){
     MouseLocator = 'on';
    });

 $$('#middleBar').invoke('observe','mouseleave',function(){
        MouseLocator = 'off';
        setTimeout(function(){HideDiv()},500);
 });
```

and a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TqMtK/9/

I guess this is resolved but I am always open to suggestions on how to improve my code :)